# Underlining with ulem package breaks footnotes

Tags: footnotes, ulem

For some reason, footnotes do not seem to work with the `ulem` package.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
    \uline{test\footnote{note}}
\end{document}
```

gives

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@footnotemark ...rk \ifhmode \spacefactor \@x@sf 
                                                  \fi \relax
```

when I try to compile it using `pdflatex`. Is there any chance to fix this or some kind of workaround?

Comment: You might use `soul` and its `\ul` command. If you're underlining a word for giving it a special meaning, then the footnote marker shouldn't be underlined anyway and the standard `\underline` would suffice. If you're underlining a whole sentence, emphasize it in a different way, with italics, for instance; your readers will be grateful.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But my requirements for underlining with the `ulem` package are kind of external.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put problematic parts in a box (see the documentation). But -- as Heiko reminds in the comment --  if you put the whole footnote in the box you will lose the text. So you should use `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
    \uline{test\mbox{\footnotemark}}\footnotetext{note}\uline{ blalbalb}\footnote{blub}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect example of RTFM.

Comment: `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` are needed.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Blush. That's the draw back of a too large zoom. You are completly right. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two variants of underlining:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
 %   \uline{test\footnote{note}}

 \uline{test}\footnote{note}

or

{test}\footnote{ \uline{note}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Underlining should not be used at all, anyways. And it certainly makes no sense to underline a text that is long enough to contain a footnote.

Comment: There are certainly use cases, where underlining makes sense - regardless of the footnotes. Judging underlining is not part of the question.