# Comfortable solution for using ulem together with (r)eledmac

Tags: footnotes, eledmac, reledmac, ulem, underline

*Preface: Sorry for the long text. By writing it, I was able to solve an earlier problem leading to this one.*

In [Underlining with ulem package breaks footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186176/underlining-with-ulem-package-breaks-footnotes) Ulrike Fischer and Heiko Oberdiek answer a question regarding the combination of package `ulem` and `\footnote`.

I am now confronted with a very similar problem, but with the footnote macros from package `(r)eledmac`.

How can I solve the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[noreledmac]{eledmac} % or reledmac

\begin{document}
This is \uline{a test containing\footnoteA{A simple footnote.} a simple footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Using the approach from the linked question I could use:

```
This is \uline{a test containing\mbox{\footnoteAmark}}%
   \footnoteAtext{A simple footnote.}\uline{ a simple footnote.}
```

But how do those two macros `\footnoteAmark` and `\footnoteAtext` look like?
I started with the `eledmac` manual and took relevant parts of the definition for `\footnoteA`:

```
\begingroup%
   \prepare@prenotesX{#1}%
   \newcommand{\content}{##1}%
   \stepcounter{footnote#1}%
   \protected@csxdef{@thefnmark#1}{\csuse{thefootnote#1}}%
   \csuse{@footnotemark#1}%
   \csuse{vfootnote#1}{#1}{\expandonce\content}\m@mmf@prepare%
\endgroup%
```

Now I split that up into two new definitions:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\footnoteAmark}{%
   \begingroup%
      \prepare@prenotesX{A}%
      \stepcounter{footnoteA}%
      \protected@csxdef{@thefnmarkA}{\csuse{thefootnoteA}}%
      \csuse{@footnotemarkA}%
   \endgroup%
}%
%
\newcommand{\footnoteAtext}[1]{%
   \begingroup%
      \csuse{vfootnoteA}{A}{\expandonce{#1}}\m@mmf@prepare%
   \endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
```

It works. However, as I am using this as part of an automated process, is there a way to define some `\footnoteAVar` doing the magic altogether?

```
This is \uline{a test containing\footnoteAVar{A simple footnote.} a simple footnote.}
```

My approach

```
\newcommand{\footnoteAVar}[1]{%
   \mbox{\footnoteAmark}%       
   \egroup% to end \uline
   \footnoteAtext{#1}%
   \uline\bgroup%
}%
```

results in a missing footnote text at the bottom of the page:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[noreledmac]{eledmac} % or reledmac
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\footnoteAmark}{%
   \begingroup%
      \prepare@prenotesX{A}%
      \stepcounter{footnoteA}%
      \protected@csxdef{@thefnmarkA}{\csuse{thefootnoteA}}%
      \csuse{@footnotemarkA}%
   \endgroup%
}%
%
\newcommand{\footnoteAtext}[1]{%
   \begingroup%
      \csuse{vfootnoteA}{A}{\expandonce{#1}}\m@mmf@prepare%
   \endgroup%
}%
\newcommand{\footnoteAVar}[1]{%
   \mbox{\footnoteAmark}%       
   \egroup% to end \uline
   \footnoteAtext{#1}%
   \uline\bgroup%
}%    
\makeatother    
\begin{document}
This is \uline{a test containing\mbox{\footnoteAmark}}\footnoteAtext{A  
simple footnote.}\uline{ a simple footnote.}

This is \uline{a test containing\footnoteAVar{A simple footnote.} a 
simple footnote.}
\end{document}
```

I guess my grouping is the problem. Does anybody have the missing link?

Comment: Please open an issue on github. I think that should be implemented directly in reledmac.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Martin Work, the version 2.19.0 of reledmac, which will be send quickly on CTAN, provides two new command : `\footnoteAmark` and `\footnoteAtext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend, noeledsec]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
This is \uline{a test containing\mbox{\footnoteAmark}}\footnoteAtext{A  
simple footnote.}\uline{ a simple footnote.}
\end{document}
```